# В чем преимущество оператора CASE по сравнению с IF-ELSIF?

Tags: oracle, plsql, case

В чем преимущество оператора `CASE` по сравнению с обычными списком отдельных условий `IF-ELSIF`?

Когда его стоит применять?

Comment: *Когда его стоит применять?* Всегда, кроме случаев, когда имеется только 2 альтернативы (в таких случаях - желательно просто подумать, что более читабельно).

Comment: @Akina Может не стоило минусить? Вполне нормальный вопрос.

Comment: @0xdb В книге "Язык С в XXI веке".

В главе 7 "Несущественные особенности синтаксиса С, Которым в учебниках уделяется чрезмерно много внимания"
switch был создан когда компы били слабенькие и он проваливаться, а if избыточен но при этом короче. **Но по поскольку он занимает меньше времени на написание кода и не является тонкой оберткой вокруг ничем не прикрытых меток и переходов, то и ошибку сделать сложнее.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По производительности - никакой разницы. Оба условных предложения идентичны.

В офф. документации [4-5 IF THEN ELSIF Statement Simulates Simple CASE Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-71C41E49-99FE-4837-A943-3E6115536485) упоминается:

> For this purpose, a simple **CASE statement is clearer**

Трудно не согласиться, `CASE` читается легче.

---

Преимуществом инструкции `CASE` является также то, что она имеет ещё одну синтаксическую форму - [`CASE expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-216F1B33-493F-4CDE-93BB-096BACA8523E), которая возвращает значение:

```
declare 
    function f (par number) return varchar2 is
    begin  
        return case par when 0 then 'zero' else 'non zero' end; 
    end;
begin 
    dbms_output.put_line ('f(0)='||f(0)||', f(1)='||f(1)); 
end;
/
```

> f(0)=zero, f(1)=non zero

`IF-ELSIF` имеет только одну форму - предложения (*Statement*).

Comment: *На мой взгляд, самое важное отличие - CASE может возвращать значение, а IF-ELSIF нет:* Не понял... Вы что, в принципе не видите разницу между CASE statement и CASE expression? между IF statement, IF expression и IF function?

Comment: @Akina Вижу конечно, её и описал. Или я вас не понял, вы о чём сейчас?

Comment: *её и описал* Я бы сказал - с точностью до наоборот. Вы всё свалили в кучу, тогда как надо было чётко разделить. В Оракле IF существует исключительно с форме statement. В то время как CASE существует как в форме statement (и так же, как IF, никакого значения возвращать не может), так и в форме expression (в которой может возвращать значение). Именно в этом и разница. А в других диалектах IF может существовать и как expression, и как function - и соответственно в обоих случаях возвращать значение.

Comment: _с точностью до наоборот_ - а что наоборот? Что неверного в процитированном в первом комментарии предложении?

Comment: Вы НЕ описали, когда CASE может вернуть значение, а когда нет. Когда CASE заменяет IF, значение как раз НЕ может возвращаться. Впрочем, и логика такого применения не требует значения.

Comment: 1) _Вы НЕ описали, когда CASE может вернуть значение, а когда нет_ - нет, не описал. Разве об этом вопрос? 2) _Когда CASE заменяет IF, значение как раз НЕ может возвращаться_  - безспорно, где я написал, что это не так. 3) Возможно моя формулировка в дополнении к ответу нуждается в улучшении, чтобы не была понята двусмысленно, но пока из вашиих комментариев следует, что она в корне не верна. Так почему она не верна?

Comment: @Akina, можете пояснить что такое `IF expression` и `IF function` в рамках Oracle DB?

Comment: По-моему назрело время задать вопрос (и дать на него ответ) об отличиях `CASE expression` от `CASE statement` в Oracle DB ;)

Comment: @MaxU Нашёл время и попробовал воплотить идею. Была надежда, что "легко отделаюсь" ассоцией с enSO, но там подходяшей темы чего-то нет. Как всегда -- критика и предложения по улучшению приветствуются.

Comment: @MaxU *можете пояснить что такое IF expression и IF function в рамках Oracle DB?* Я же вроде чётко указал, что "В Оракле IF существует исключительно с форме statement.". *назрело время задать вопрос (и дать на него ответ) об отличиях CASE expression от CASE statement в Oracle DB* [CASE Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037), [Simple CASE Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-3937FEB2-96A1-456B-AD9E-09B627DF0939) и чуть ниже Searched CASE Statement.

Comment: @Akina, цитирую первый комментарий: « Вы что, в принципе не видите разницу между CASE statement и CASE expression? между IF statement, IF expression и IF function?» Вот мне и стало интересно узнать о « IF expression и IF function» Это я не сам придумал! ;)

Comment: @MaxU Насчёт "IF expression и IF function" - это "в общем"... даже скорее "вдогонку". Ибо вопрос хоть и тегован для Оракла, но имеет общий характер. Ошибкой же для данной конкретной DBMS является только не-разделение для CASE.

Comment: @Akina Вопрос вполне конкретный, потому что с тэгом [oracle] и об отличиях с другими диалектами в нём не спрашивается.  _не-разделение для CASE_, а что это за ошибка, извините, но я не понял.

Comment: @0xdb Ещё раз. Вы безусловно утверждаете, что "CASE может возвращать значение, а IF-ELSIF нет". Без каких-либо оговорок. А это неверно, ибо "может" относится к вполне определённому типу - CASE expression. Более того, применительно к вопросу - там, где IF заменяется на CASE, используется CASE statement, который, как и IF, значения не возвращает.

Comment: @Akina Хорошо, вроде начинаю понимать. Попозже попробую улучшить формулировку и указать на разные типы инструкции CASE. Лучше было сразу предложить улучшающую правку одним предложением для более конструктивного обсуждения.

Comment: @Akina Внёс правку. Посмотрите, достаточно ли для устранения _ не-разделение для CASE_?

Comment: Да, конечно, достаточно. В принципе это, конечно, создатели языка, скажем так, зря сделали - абсолютно одинаковые по написанию, но две совершенно разные по смыслу, конструкции... слова SWITCH не знали, что ли?