# В чём основное отличие CASE expression от CASE statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

В чём основное отличие [CASE statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-3937FEB2-96A1-456B-AD9E-09B627DF0939) от [CASE expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-216F1B33-493F-4CDE-93BB-096BACA8523E)?

Как известно, иннструкция `CASE expression` происходит из SQL и была добавлена в PL/SQL когда `CASE statement` уже там присутсвовала.

В документации для `CASE statement` упоминается:

> The CASE statement is appropriate when a different action is to be taken for each alternative.

А для `CASE expression`:

> The simple CASE expression returns the first result for which selector_value matches selector.

То есть, при выполнении условия будет выполнено определённое действие как для одной иннструкции, так и для другой.

Разве отличие только в том, что `CASE expression` возвращает значение и может быть использована в обычном SQL запросе, а `CASE statement` нет? Тогда почему не использовать только `CASE expression` в PL/SQL контексте?

Comment: связанный вопрос:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1052674/217579

Answer (score 6):

`CASE expression` может быть только частью законченного предложения (т.е. завершённого символом `;`), всегда возвращает **одно значение** как результат выполнения выражения при выполнении первого условия. Причём, выполняемое выражение может быть сложным и состоять из нескольких выражений резделёных операторами.

```
declare cond number := 0;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line ( 
        case 
        when cond > 0 then 'gt as '||0||'(first condition)' 
        when cond = 0 then 'equal '||0||'(second condition)'
        else 'zero '||0||'(else)' end
    );
end;
/

equal 0(second condition)
```

`CASE statement` это само по себе законченное предложение, которое выполняет **серию предложений** (*statements*), в простейшем случае одно, при выполнении первого условия. Каждое предложение является законченным, т.е. не возвращает никакого значения.

```sql
declare 
    cond number := 0;
    res varchar2 (16);
    procedure proc1 is begin dbms_output.put_line ('in proc1'); end;
    function func1 return varchar2 is begin return 'in func1'; end;
begin
    case 
    when cond > 0 then proc1; 
    when cond = 0 then 
        res := func1;
        proc1;
        dbms_output.put_line (res);
    else dbms_output.put_line (func1);
    end case;
end;
/

in proc1
in func1
```

Важное синтаксическое отличие, кроме видимого окончания `end case;` -- если никакое условие не выполнится и отсутсвует `else`, то:

- для `CASE statement` будет неявно подставленно исключение:

  ```
  ...
  else raise case_not_found;
  end case;
  ```
- `CASE expression` в этом случае вернёт `null`